# How do you make an API secure using HMAC?

Tags: api, security, hmac

I'm trying to design an API endpoint, where I verify the authenticity of requests using HMAC.

I understand that I need to provide the client `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET`.

The questions I have are:

- Should `API_SECRET` be derived from `API_KEY` using some secret salt on the server?
- Should I be storing `API_SECRET` somewhere? I understand I'll need this to authenticate requests, but my concern about leaving it in the DB is that a db hack would expose all `API_SECRET`s.
- What is the point of having an `API_KEY` and an `API_SECRET`? Is the `API_KEY` analogous to a username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should API_SECRET be derived from API_KEY using some secret salt on the server?

No. Keys are public information, secrets should be randomly generated using cryptographically-secure PRNGs. If a secret is derived from a key, then anyone discovering the derivation method would be able to derive the secret for any key they could discover!

> Should I be storing API_SECRET somewhere?

Yes. How else will you use it to verify HMAC signatures?

You could add an additional layer of armor by storing the secret encrypted with a key that is kept outside of the database, though a more complete hack would be able to discover it, as well.

You can't hash the secret like you would with a password, because you need it as an input to the HMAC to verify the signature, so you need reversible encryption of some sort.

> What is the point of having an API_KEY and an API_SECRET? Is the API_KEY analogous to a username?

Broadly, yes. For HMAC, all you need is a shared secret. However, you need to know *which* shared secret to attempt to validate the request with. The API_KEY provides you a way to look up the secret that the request claims to be signed by, then you can validate the request by computing the signature with your own copy of the secret and doing a (constant-time) comparison to the provided signature.